# Animating color changes from top to bottom and vice versa

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

Im trying to animate color change as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     NSLog(@"Color transformation Completed");
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
         self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     } completion:^(BOOL finished)
      {
          NSLog(@"Color transformation Completed");
      }

      ];
 }
 ];
```

I want the color to flow from top to bottom as it fills the entire screen with green color and it  should fill from bottom to top with white color.

So I have used `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` while filling green and `options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` while filling with white but Im unable to get the desired effect..why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` only describes how your animations would act as. For example, `EaseIn` means the speed of the animation is slow at first then fast.

So if you'd like to implement this animation, you can set 2 `UIView`s with green and white color, then change their `frame`s through animation.